# How to save images in Snowflake and obtain links to them?

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to save image files in the Snowflake database and obtain links to them for inserting images on websites.

Currently, I store image files in the following table:

```
IMAGES (
    PRIMARY_KEY NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL autoincrement,
    IMAGE BINARY(8388608),
    primary key (PRIMARY_KEY)
);
```

How can I obtain the link to an image from this setup?

Comment: [Introduction to Unstructured Data Support](https://docs.snowflake.com/user-guide/unstructured-intro)